# I haven't been able to open a jar file in 3 years

Tags: java

This began in late 2017 seemingly out of nowhere on a brand new PC; every single jar file fails to load for an unknown reason. The paths are correct, my computer recognizes Java and I have reinstalled it dozens of times with no luck and have followed the dozens of tutorials on what may be/fix the issue.

- Yes I have to correct version of java (including Java Runtime Environment) with the jdk/jre
- jarfix doesn't work
- All of the paths under environment variables are correct
- I have the correct and most updated version for my Windows 10 system
- The problem persists with and without anti-malware software and similar software alike
- I am unable to open .jar files with CMD prompt, it sits and doesn't execute
- .jar files don't even load on a virtual desktop on this system
- I have completely reset my system multiple times with no luck
- I receive no error messages of any kind

What in gods name do I do? My friends couldn't fix it, my software engineer uncle couldn't fix it and Oracles support couldn't fix it. I am at a complete loss with weekends of frustration and anger.

Comment: I might suggest taking this question over to SuperUser instead. Even though it loosely has to do with Java, this isn't really a programming question.

Comment: Was late 2017 perhaps the time you updated from earlier-than-Java 7 Update 51 to that or later version? At that version, [the application signing became mandatory.](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/java_blocked.html) If the JAR files you've been testing pre-date that requirement (or are created with an old procedure that does not include signing them), that might explain it. Also, in April 2017, [MD5 signatures were no longer considered good.](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/oracle-jre-will-no-longer-trust-md5-signed-code-by-default)

Comment: You might try uninstalling the Oracle JVM and install another JVM. See [this page which describes the non-Oracle JVM's which are available](https://dev.lucee.org/t/non-oracle-jdks-overview-of-options/4846). I've got OpenJDK installed on my Linux Mint system and I haven't noticed any difference between it and the official Oracle-supplied JVM for my uses (principally jEdit (programmer's editor written in Java) and Clojure (Lisp variant which runs on the JVM)).

Comment: "I am unable to open .jar files with CMD prompt, it sits and doesn't execute" @DanielB

Comment: On my Win10 machine, when I type the name of a valid jar file in CMD.EXE shell followed by the "enter/return key", I get a popup asking how to open the file.
How are your file associations set?  Are jar files associated with the correct java executeable path?
Any error message when you submit the JAR file on the CMD prompt?
What OS are you using?

Comment: Have you tried to run the same  JAR on another computer ? How do you generate your JAR files ? Is there some Java code or webpage that you could share so that we can try to reproduce the issue ? What command do you run in CMD.EXE and what is its output ?